# Como separar e manipular dados do select com js

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

Tenho um fórum com um campo `select` que possui muitas opções para selecionar, gostaria de dividir essas opções por área do fórum em dois `select`.

Todas as áreas e sub-áreas ficam em um único `select`.

Exemplo:

```
<div class="blockrow">
                <label for="destforumid">Fórum de Destino:</label>
                <select id="destforumid" name="destforumid" class="primary" tabindex="1">
    <option value="5" class="d0">Feedback (Categoria)</option>
    <option value="23" class="d0">Fórum de Estudos (Categoria)</option>
    <option value="7" class="d1">&nbsp; &nbsp; Anúncios e Enquetes</option>
    <option value="19" class="d1">&nbsp; &nbsp; Fale Conosco (Link)</option>

    <option value="10" class="d0">Designs (Categoria)</option>
    <option value="14" class="d2">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Pedidos</option>
    <option value="29" class="d3">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Atendidos (Sem Postagem)</option>
</select>
```

Pelo que pude ver, `d0` é a cátegoria, não é fórum. `d1` é um fórum do `d0` acima e quando houver um `d2` abaixo do `d2`, é um sub-fórum, ou seja, um fórum dentro do fórum `d1` que está na categoria `d0`.

Se houver dois `d2`, quer dizer que existem 2 fóruns nessa categoria, bem simples de entender. no caso de um `d3` depois de um `d2`, quer dizer que o `d2` anterior que é um fórum, vai ter um outro fórum dentro, que é o `d3`. E assim por diante, podendo haver vários `d1`, `d2`, `d3`, `d4`...

As categorias são divididas a cada novo `d0`.

Gostaria de obter todos esses valores com js, onde no primeiro, atual `select` eu selecionaria apenas as categorias que desejo, e no segundo eu selecionaria o subfórum dessa categoria selecionada que desejo.

Todos os `select` tem um dado, o `value`, são eles que identificam o local selecionado.

O segundo select teria que ter os dados `id="destforumid" name="destforumid" class="primary" tabindex="1"` pois sem isso talvez não funcionasse.

Como eu poderia fazer com que o javascript capturasse automaticamente esses dados do `select` e organizassem da forma descrita acima em 2 `select` para que não ficasse uma lista enorme?

Comment: Obs: Deixei o select com poucas opções, suficientes para o exemplo e entendimento, mas no fórum são centenas se áreas, por isso a divisão facilitaria e muito.

Comment: O primeiro não seria igual, esqueci de por na pergunta esse detalhe, o primeiro serviria apenas para as categorias, o segundo é o que realmente iria selecionar. No caso do select ```Feedback (Categoria)```, ele não tem nenhum sub-fórum, teria que repetir ele no segundo select.

Comment: O primeiro seria apenas com as categorias, apenas os ```d0```, o segundo com as sub-áreas do d0 selecionado, que vão do ```d0``` até o próximo.

Comment: Não importa muito como seja, desde que quando selecionado uma categoria, o segundo select lista os subfóruns pertencentes a ela, para aí sim escolher no segundo select.

Comment: Uma função poderia remover o select existente, depois de ter pego os dados, ai criaria o primeiro select das categorias, e o segundo com o id que queremos. Não daria certo assim? @dvd

Comment: Se não for prejudicar a exibição das subáreas pode ficar sim, caso atrapalhe, qualquer nome pode ser usado, pois para o vbulletin o que vai importar é o ```id="destforumid" name="destforumid"``` que vai estar no segundo select.

Comment: Blz, vou fazer aqui e qq ajuste a gente vê.

Comment: Outra dúvida: pode ser com jQuery?

Comment: Pode ser com o que você quiser :)

Comment: Você pode repetir ele, ou seja, ele seria seu próprio valor no segundo select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creio que seja isso que quer. Percorrer o primeiro `select` e colocar no segundo as subcategorias de acordo com a categoria selecionada.

**Veja:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".blockrow select")
   .attr({
      id: "primeiro",
      name: ""
   });

   $("#primeiro option[class!='d0']").hide(); // escondo tudo que não tiver a classe 'd0'
   
   $("<select>", {
      id: "destforumid",
      name: "destforumid",
      class: "primary",
      tabindex: "1"
   })
   .insertAfter("#primeiro");
   
   var cats = $("#primeiro option");
   
   $("#primeiro").on("change", function(){
      
      var opt = $(this)
                .find("option:selected")
                .nextUntil(".d0"),
          htm = '';

      if(opt.length == 0){
         htm = $(this)
               .find("option:selected")
               .clone();
      }else{
         $(opt).each(function(i,e){
            htm += e.outerHTML;
         });
      }

      $("#destforumid")
      .empty()
      .append(htm)
      .find("option")
      .show();

   }).trigger("change");
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blockrow">
   <label for="destforumid">Fórum de Destino:</label>
   <select id="destforumid" name="destforumid" class="primary" tabindex="1">
      <option value="5" class="d0">Feedback (Categoria)</option>
      <option value="23" class="d0">Fórum de Estudos (Categoria)</option>
      <option value="7" class="d1">&nbsp; &nbsp; Anúncios e Enquetes</option>
      <option value="19" class="d1">&nbsp; &nbsp; Fale Conosco (Link)</option>

      <option value="10" class="d0">Designs (Categoria)</option>
      <option value="14" class="d2">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Pedidos</option>
      <option value="29" class="d3">&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; Atendidos (Sem Postagem)</option>
   </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Esse segundo select teria que ser inserido no código html, visto que essas mudanças só podem ser feitas via javascript e não no próprio código da página. A pagina é carregada com um único menu, e o javascript deve executar essas mudanças, teria como você atualizar este código para fazer isso? Não consegui aqui pois o segundo menu não existe.

Comment: Resposta atualizada.

Comment: Não deu muito certo, os dados são dinâmicos, então o ```<select id="primeiro"...``` não pode ter esses valores predefinidos. O menu é carregado como demonstrei na pergunta, em ```html```, tudo o que vamos modificar na pagina tem de ser em javascript, pois não posso inserir nada predefinido nela como um segundo ```select```, tudo deve ser feito com ```javascript```. Não sei se fui claro, por favor me diga se tiver alguma duvida.

Comment: O código js acima acha que existe esse ```id="primeiro"``` no html, mas ele não tem, a não ser que coloquemos via javascript, o que vem no html é o menu padrão como mostrei na pergunta, acho que o problema esta sendo isso.

Comment: Não tinha me atentado a isso... alterei a resposta

Comment: Perfeito, nessa atualização que você fez está funcional. :)